# How to stop window 10 pop-up behaviour (from right-corner bar) "Can't install updates" pop-up

Tags: windows, popups

**Problems**

The **"Can't install updates"** pop-up scheduled "when PC started up" behaviour is uncontrollable. No normal selective toggle button in "setting" related to this behaviour.

[image]

**Windows 10** : OS Name    Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

**Tried solutions** :

1. Registry Editor - Stop upload policy

[image]

2.disablettmedic.bat

```
echo Windows Update Medic Service
sc stop WaasMedicSvc
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaasMedicSvc /v Start /f /t REG_DWORD /d 4
echo.


echo Servizio Windows Update
sc stop wuauserv
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv /v Start /f /t REG_DWORD /d 4
echo.


echo Aggiorna il servizio Orchestrator
sc stop UsoSvc
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsoSvc /v Start /f /t REG_DWORD /d 4
echo.
```

3. All "off" toggle button for stopping notifications in "Settings" .

**Things I Cannot stop** :

1. `svchost, C:\Windows\System32`  -- update orchestrate service
2. `wuauserv`  -- Windows Update

The accessibilities are blocked to "disable" but only "manual". Apparently those methods do not work and those update services are very suspicious.

**Desired solutions**

1. DESTORY the whole scheduled update checking task .
   or
2. Stop only the **pop-up motion** but let window run whatever it wants.

No harm for the OS running any diagnosis behind but it cannot override ALL apps without manual control e.g. pop-up above all fullscreen status , gaming , movie playing e.t.c.

Comment: Are you trying to disable Windows Updates, or have you already disabled them and you want this warning to go away, or are you trying to fix a problem with Windows Updates, or something else?

Comment: any solution to prevent the pop-up is perfect

Comment: It's really not. Your computer needs an update, and you should get it installed as the correct way to make the popup go away as it will solve the underlying problem. Which update is this? With your build of 18363, you really should install the latest updates.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/153s2NaqneENWnkUIoWmDLtHt-Myw0TEj/view?usp=share_link   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FjlOiQhZJQFERVK8cdYxwPAoUUBNYPVC/view?usp=share_link

Comment: The most basic windows update . I don't against the update but what need to take control is the compulsory  "OVERRIDE" pop-up on top of every app you are running ,and that is your own computer , not microsoft , we just brought the software not right to stop what i am doing .  Most desired solution is what we can add / adjust to stop this behaviour. `sc config wuauserv start= disabled` cannot prevent it turn on again .

Comment: We don't really like clicking unexplained Google drive links. Please tell us which update is unable to install.